# Why DatePicker Parses dates in MM.dd.yyyy format even though I strictly told it to Parse dates in dd.MM.yyyy format

Tags: c#, wpf, date, datepicker

I have a DatePicker control in WPF. I want it to display dates in dd.MM.yyyy format.

So, I added the below lines of code to Application_StartUp event:

```
CultureInfo culInfo = new CultureInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);
DateTimeFormatInfo dtinfo = new DateTimeFormatInfo()
                                {
                                    ShortDatePattern = "dd.MM.yyyy",
                                    ShortTimePattern = "hh:mm:ss tt",
                                    TimeSeparator = ":",
                                    MonthNames = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames,
                                    AbbreviatedMonthNames = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames,
                                    DateSeparator = "."
                                };

culInfo.DateTimeFormat = dtinfo;
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culInfo;
```

Now datePicker shows dates in dd.MM.yyyy format as expected.

Then I tried to enter **day** and Pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>. For e.g. 01 <kbd>Enter</kbd>. I expected to get month and year automatically from the date that was previously selected or if any date is not selected then the month and year should be from today's date. But my expectation was wrong. I get DatePicker's TextBox empty when I pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Then I tried to enter **day and month** and Pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>. For e.g. 01.03 <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This time I expected that the TextBox should be cleared or it should add year as I expected in the last case. And when I show result, I was shocked. My expectations were partially fulfilled. I mean I entered 01.03 and pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>, I got 03.01.2014 in the TextBox. Now my question is why date is converted to MM.dd.yyyy format? I expected it to be in dd.MM.yyyy. I always get dates in dd.MM.yyyy as you can see in the code above. Also Locale of my computer is set to dd-MM-yyyy.

What I really want :

1. As I mentioned in above paragraph, I want date in dd.MM.yyyy format when I enter day and month and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. I want same behaviour when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after entering just the date.

Comment: Setting aside the control for a moment... After the block of code you provided, if you create a string and set it to "01.03.2014" and then execute a plain-vanilla datetime.parse on it, what do you get in the returned DateTime object?

Comment: In that case I get the output as 01.03.2014 00:00:00.

Comment: I used this code to get above output: string s = "01.03.2014";
            DateTime d = DateTime.Parse(s);
            MessageBox.Show(d.ToString());

Comment: Right, but which month is IN the object?  1 or 3?

Comment: Day = 1 and Month = 3

Comment: If I remove the code mentioned in the question then also I get Day = 1 and Month = 3.

Comment: I have just found that DatePicker works as expected if I remove the code mentioned in the question. But my client(s) might not have set their DateTime in dd.MM.yyyy format. So, I tried that code. Also I need to change the separator from `/` to `.`.

Comment: where did you tell the control which format to use? not in the code you provided.

Comment: @Vishal, that means you should delete this question and ask how to change the separator for a specific culture.

Comment: @speising Yes I tell the control to use dd.MM.yyyy in above code only. But If I remove the above mentioned code, then it picks up its format from my computer's locale.

Comment: @GayotFow As you say I can ask another question for separator purpose. But my clients will get problem if their computer's locale is not set to dd.MM.yyyy. So, I need an answer to the above question as well.

Comment: @Vishal, your DateTimeFormatInfo class is set up such that certain properties are defaulting to the invariant culture.  And if you insist that your clients use a hard-coded culture with a .NET control, then your design is misconceived.

Comment: @GayotFow So, What can I do more for DateTimeInfo class? And my design is not mis-conceived as my clients are illeterate people and they don't even know how to change their computer's locale. So, I will have to use hard-coded culture in my code. Also my application will not be used outside the area of my development as it is developed in local Language.

Comment: Multi-culti developers do not care about the end user's locale.  Perhaps solving that would make a better question.

Comment: @GayotFow Sorry, I did not understand : Perhaps solving that would make a better question.

Comment: Ask how to get multi-culti with the DateTime picker!